# Alternative MySQL administration system similar to phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am trying to switch from PHP to Golang and since I am so used to phpMyAdmin and a graphical interface when dealing with MySQL I was wondering if there were any good alternatives to phpMyAdmin that didn't need PHP. Since I don't want to have PHP installed on my webserver when I'm not going to use PHP. Is there perhaps any softwares that can be used to log into via ssh or something similar connecting remotely? Is there a good alternative?

Comment: Which functionalities do you want to use exactly? PhpMyAdmin allows you to do a lot of configuration out of the box, but it's not a given that you need all of that? Do you wish to perform queries? To see what is in your tables? To see the table structure?

Comment: To see what is in the tables, do sql queries, edit row values for testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting through SSH you can create secure tunnels easily and use the [MySQL workbench tool](http://mysqlworkbench.org).

It's an official tool from MySQL, multi-platform and easy to use. It also has other nice features like an ERD editor.

Comment: Does it cost money? I see it is from Oracle

Comment: Should work 95%, the protocol its the same but you will not have access to specific mariadb implementations.

Comment: And no, no money. Its GNU and probably its included in the oficial repos of your linux distro of choice.

Comment: This one looks nice, is opensource and supports many dbs https://www.beekeeperstudio.io/